# Clicking on button doesnt work

Tags: javascript, function

Clicking on button doesnt do anything. Please help. Is there a better way to do it? 
https://pasteboard.co/Hj3FATA.png

Comment: Is there any error in the Javascript console?

Comment: Save and link the JSFiddle or include your code in your post.

Comment: No no error, nothing happens when i click on button. Perhaps a problem with invoking, idk why it isnt working.

Comment: I dont know how to link it here

Comment: remove the '20, 40' arguments from your function

Comment: Im trying to call a function with numbers i give, it would work without 20 and 40 but i want to define para1 and para2